# What is the difference between "don't think it!" and "don't think about it!"?

Tags: difference, phrase-usage

What is the difference between *don't think it!* and *don't think about it!*? For example:

> Person A: I think I will flunk the test.
>
> Person B: **Don't think it**!/**Don't think about it**!